# Creating invoices in bulk using NetSuite REST API

Tags: netsuite, invoice, suitetalk

Is there a way to create multiple invoices with a single POST request to the NetSuite REST API?

The [API Reference](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2021.1/index.html#tag-invoice) doesn't mention anything - but I'm hoping there's a way to avoid sending thousands of individual requests.

I am creating a single invoice like this (some headers have been removed):

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://{{COMPANY_URL}}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/invoice' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "entity": {
        "id": 46
    },
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "id": 134
                },
                "amount": 20
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

Comment: I believe that the only way to do this is to create your own endpoint via a Restlet.